# PHP Google AppEngine - php.ini - differentiate between local and dev environment

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, curl

Due to a quirk with Google's CURL implementation, I want to use extension = "curl.so" locally within my php.ini and curl lite within the production environment. I'm currently changing the php.ini manually each time before running **appcfg.py update .** but is there a way to set this automagically?

```
; Local dev env
extension = "curl.so"

; Production env
; google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

Comment: Can you not use the PHP.ini in the application root for production?

Comment: Why not use curl lite for your local development as well?

Comment: @Mars with Curl lite locally I receive an error "CurlLiteOptionNotSupportedException' with message 'Option 10065 is not supported by this curl implementation.'" and I receive a different set of errors using curl.so in production AppEngine, so this was the workaround

Comment: @Tom It was my understanding AppEngine uses PHP.ini in the application root for both local and production? If was possible to direct AppEngine local to use a different PHP.ini that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Are you trying to set CURLOPT_CAINFO? And doing that in production doesn't cause CurlLiteOptionNotSupportedException?

Comment: @mars I'm just using the default vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/IO/Curl.php which doesn't cause any problems in production.